# CompareTo wrong element being expected

Tags: java, arrays, string, compareto

I have the following code; the intent is to return the smallest, alphabetically, member of an array.

```java
public String smallest() {
String smallest = "";
int i = 0;
while(log[i] != null) {
    int nextIndex = i+1;
    if(log[nextIndex] == null) {
        break;
    }
    if(log[i].compareToIgnoreCase(log[nextIndex]) >0) {
        smallest = log[nextIndex];
    }
    else {
        smallest = log[i];
    }
    i++;
}
if(log[i].compareToIgnoreCase(smallest) <0) {
    smallest = log[i];
}
return smallest;
}
```

When I run the tester, two of the tests fail and the other two proceed fine. The first one is an example of a successful test, and the latter is an example of one of the failing tests.

```java
public void test_3Elements_smallest_in_middle() {
    strLog.insert("string 2"); strLog.insert("string 1");
    strLog.insert("string 3"); 

    assertEquals(strLog.smallest(), "string 1");
}

public void test_3Elements_smallest_at_beginning() {
    strLog.insert("string 1"); strLog.insert("string 2");
    strLog.insert("string 3"); 

    assertEquals(strLog.smallest(), "string 1");
}
```

What in the world can I do to fix this? To be more specific, for the latter one, the one that's failing, it gives me an error about it was expecting string[2] but it was string[1]. Which confuses me; if it can pick out the smallest in the middle of the array, why can't it pick out the smallest in the beginning?

Comment: What does compareTo() have to do with it? Accurate titles please.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're overcomplicating things, when this one-line solution would do the job:

```
return Collections.min(Arrays.asList(log), String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Comment: From what I can tell...that returns the smallest element of the Array, since it gets ordered alphabetically, but what does the String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER at the end do?

Comment: ...Oops, didn't know the enter key would automatically send my comment. When I run it now I get a NullPointerException; I read elsewhere that means that some of the strings in the collection aren't initialized, but that shouldn't matter if we're simply sorting alphabetically and grabbing the first one, should it?

Comment: No, that totally matters; nulls are perfectly valid citizens of a `String[]`.  What you should probably be doing is using an `ArrayList` instead of a bare array, and doing `Collections.min` on that.  The `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` at the end says to use `compareToIgnoreCase`, basically, rather than the default case-sensitive ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming java something like this should work. I did not test it out.  C# has a similiar for syntax. can be done with indexes but this is cleaner.

```
public String smallest() {
    String smallest = log[0]; //assumes atleast one element in list

    for (String message : log){
       if ( message != null && message.compareToIgnoreCase(smallest) < 0 ){
         smallest = message;
       }
    }

    return message;

    }
```

In your code at this point :

```
if(log[i].compareToIgnoreCase(log[nextIndex]) >0) {
    smallest = log[nextIndex];
}
```

you are only comparing two consecutive items in the list and not all the items in the list. This is why your answer is wrong. This would work if the list was sorted but then it would be simple to get the smallest item out in the first place.

Comment: Any possible way to sort the array then? I've tried other things but the code gets extremely complex and gives more problems.

Comment: @noka there are existing library functions to sort arrays. Have a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, your algorithm is not well-defined. You are comparing items to their next. Try this instead:

```
String minText = log[0];

for (int i = 1; i < log.length; i++)
{
    if (minText.compareToIgnoreCase(log[i]) > 0)
    {
        minText = log[i];
    }
}
```

Louis Wasserman is also correct, but I wanted to show you the algorithm. Basically we initially set the minText to be the first element in the log. Then, from the second element till the last element, we are always looking whether the current element is smaller than the currently stored minText. If so, we assign that value to minText.

Comment: I'm actually pretty close to it with this answer! All of the tests save 1 work with this. The test in question is: 'public void test_3Elements_smallest_at_end() {
  strLog.insert("string 3"); strLog.insert("string 2");
  strLog.insert("string 1"); 
  
  assertEquals(strLog.smallest(), "string 1");
 } '

Comment: Apologies for the 's in the previous comment. This is new to me and it said 's were code. Anyway, the modified smallest() code is now:public String smallest() {
 
 String smallest = log[0];

 for (int i = 1; i < log.length; i++)
 {
  int nextIndex = i+1;
  if(log[nextIndex] == null) {
   break;
  }
     if (smallest.compareToIgnoreCase(log[i]) > 0)
     {
         smallest = log[i];
     }
 }
 return smallest;
}

Comment: Please, do not use the same name for a variable and a method. No need for nextIndex either. if nextIndex > log.length, then it will not be null. Instead a NullPointerException will be thrown, which is not a nice thing (to describe it in simple terms). So, you should either use Louis Wasserman's or my solution. Both of the solutions should solve your problem. And I repeat: there is no point to have a nextIndex variable. You are over-complicating things if you use that. A clean solution iterates the array and stores the smallest String. You can do it, I trust you.

Comment: If I use your code barebones, it gives me a NullPointerException. With the code I modified and put above, it works fine except for one test, where it expects string 2 but it was string 1.

Comment: The NullPointerException is thrown when a reference is not initialized. So, my question is: what is the stack-trace of the exception in your case?